# Extract Subset String from Long String Between Markers

Tags: python, pandas, string, list

i have a list of long strings like this below and I need to extract a subset of string and save as new list the characters between two markers in each long string. For example, two of my strings looks like this using ".Power" as a marker and the preceding "."

```
'\\\\porfiler03\\\\gtdshare\\\\VORTEX\\\\OBS\\\\ALL\\999999.Brazil.BRASIL.CAETITE III.Power.csv'
'\\\\porfiler03\\\\gtdshare\\\\VORTEX\\\\OBS\\\\ALL\\999999.Brazil.BRASIL.SANTANA II.Power.csv'
```

I need to extract this subset of each long list like this between the "." and ".Power" -

```
CAETITE III
SANTANA II
```

My code to extract the list of all the long strings, which is the path and filename, looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
from sys import exit
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

path = r'\\porfiler03\\gtdshare\\VORTEX\\OBS\\ALL\\' # use your path

all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*BRASIL*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(filename)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

exit()
```

Comment: Pandas dataframes are certainly not need for this problem, so unless you are using the dataframe for other purposes.  @Samwise gives a couple possibilities in his answer which are more generic python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> filename = '\\\\porfiler03\\\\gtdshare\\\\VORTEX\\\\OBS\\\\ALL\\999999.Brazil.BRASIL.CAETITE III.Power.csv'
```

With `re.sub`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'.*\.(.*)\.Power.*', r'\1', filename)
'CAETITE III'
```

With `split`:

```
>>> filename.split('.')[-3]
'CAETITE III'
```

or maybe:

```
>>> (lambda a: a[a.index('Power')-1])(filename.split('.'))
'CAETITE III'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex and the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) library, see a demo here: https://regex101.com/r/8EYszl/1/

```py
import re

pat = re.compile(r"\.([\w ]+)\.power", re.I)

for filename in all_files:
    match = pat.search(filename)
    print(match.group(1))
# CAETITE III
# SANTANA II
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this? using pandas' `extract` method

```
df['path'].str.extract(r'\.([\w ]+)\.Power')
             0
0  CAETITE III
1   SANTANA II
```